# C++ InternetOpenUrlW - Memory usage

Tags: c++, memory, visual-studio-2013

**UPDATE:** Thanks for the replies. I think I understand why this happens and what I could possibly try to reduce memory usage. Also, yes I use InternetCloseHandle but it doesnt change memory usage.

I'm writing a simple C++ application. One of the methods downloads a **very small** file into memory and returns it as string.

However, I noticed that one particular part of the code makes my program take up 7x more memory (from 1mb to 7mb) which I find weird and I would like to avoid it. Below is a code snippet explaining when the memory usage spike happens:

```
//InternetOpenW() doesnt trigger memory usage spike.
hOpen = InternetOpenW(L"MyAgent", NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);
if (!hOpen) return NULL;

//When InternetOpenUrlW() runs, the memory spikes.
hFile = InternetOpenUrlW(hOpen, szUrl, NULL, NULL, INTERNET_FLAG_RELOAD | INTERNET_FLAG_DONT_CACHE, NULL);
if (!hFile) 
{
    InternetCloseHandle(hOpen);
    return NULL;
}
```

The memory usage never goes back down so I wonder if its possible to do something about it.

---

It was suggested that I check modules loaded when InternetOpenUrlW() is executed. Below is the output of modules loaded ONLY by this step. However, Im not gonna lie, I have no idea what does that mean or how I should proceed.

```
'Application.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\mswsock.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'Application.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\IPHLPAPI.DLL'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'Application.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\winnsi.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'Application.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\wship6.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'Application.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\api-ms-win-downlevel-shlwapi-l2-1-0.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'Application.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\dnsapi.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'Application.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\clbcatq.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'Application.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\oleaut32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'Application.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\WSHTCPIP.DLL'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'Application.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\netprofm.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'Application.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\nlaapi.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'Application.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\dhcpcsvc6.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'Application.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\rasadhlp.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'Application.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\urlmon.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'Application.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\dhcpcsvc.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'Application.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cryptsp.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'Application.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\rsaenh.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'Application.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\RpcRtRemote.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'Application.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\npmproxy.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'Application.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\FWPUCLNT.DLL'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'Application.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\winsxs\x86_microsoft.windows.common-controls_6595b64144ccf1df_6.0.7601.18807_none_41e554362bd82458\comctl32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'Application.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ws2_32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'Application.exe' (Win32): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ws2_32.dll'
```

Comment: As you've mentioned nothing about *how* you measured this mystery memory spike, shall we assume you simply observed some number in task manager? And perchance, what are the *modules* that are loaded with that function call (hint: run it under a debugger such as your VS2013's integrated debugger, single-step on that line, and watch your Output window. the results may surprise you).

Comment: @WhozCraig Yes, I simply checked in task manager. I might try checking in a different way if its needed. As to the modules, I added a section about it in the main post.

Comment: That list is at-least contributing to your increase in footprint. They are the libs used (or potentially used) by that API call. With each comes some minimal baggage. Once mapped into your address space and initialized (which is *likely* where the footprint bump comes from) you kind of have to live with the results. Btw, 7MB is literally *nothing* even on Windows Phone devices. Is it really that important or are youjust fulfilling a curiosity?

Comment: I was kinda curious about what that function even did, so I looked it up. On MSDN it says _"After the calling application has finished using the HINTERNET handle returned by InternetOpenUrl, it must be closed using the InternetCloseHandle function."_ Calling that might solve your memory usage not going down problem.

Comment: @WhozCraig Thanks for explanation. 7mb is not alot and definitely, its not a problem for my application. However, since Im learning to code in C++, I want to know what is going on. Who knows, maybe next time Ill be constrained in terms of memory. Even if i cant lower the memory usage, at least I learned something so thanks again.

Comment: Yes, you need to close the handle once you're done with it (this will likely avoid a small memory leak over time). The 7MB is almost certainly the DLLs being loaded when the function is first called, as others have mentioned -- you can see this for yourself by observing the memory effects on subsequent calls (which should be very near zero).

Comment: @LesleyGushurst I attached only a snippet of the code and In full version I use "InternetCloseHandle". I even checked the memory usage right before this function is called and right after - the memory usage didnt change.